# MapReduce execution sequence on Single Node

Tags: hadoop

I am learning Hadoop. 
I am running Hadoop on single node. 
According to my knowledge Reducer runs after completion of Mapper (and it makes sense as well). 
 
But when i ran MapReduce job on 200MB file, Reducer started before completion of Mapper. I didn't use any Combiner. 
Can anyone explain why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reduce phase involves copying and merging the output of the data from the mappers to the reducer.

Since copying and merging intermediate outputs does not need a barrier (you don't need to wait on all mappers to complete), that's what the reducer is doing while the mappers run.

Comment: How will this concept of combining and merging before completion of Mapper work in multi-node cluster scenario? All values related to one key has to be passed to one reducer only.

Comment: @MitalAwachat that's the job of the partitioner, by default is hashes your key so it is guaranteed to land in the same partition of a reducer.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that no reduce() calls happen until the reduce phase hits 66% (i.e. when the shuffle and sort is completed).